# installing GD and gdmodule python ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, python

I am having trouble installing the gd library and gdmodule for python firstly I have done

sudo apt-get install mercurial
sudo apt-get install libgd2-xpm-dev
then trying to install the gd module using sudo python Setup.py install which I downloaded from http://newcenturycomputers.net/projects/gdmodule.html

I get the warning WARNING: missing gd, jpeg, png, gif, z, x11, Xmp, rtf, freetype Libraries Can't Find GD Libraries

How can I install both properly, I get no errors when installing the first two. I am completely stuck and I am very new to using Ubuntu, so do not know a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The latest release of these python bindings for gd are already in the Ubuntu repositories (at least of Ubuntu 12.04, "precise pangolin"), so you should just be able to do this:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gd
```

Unless you need recent changes that have not yet been published to the world as part of an official release of the bindings, or you want to make changes to the source code yourself, there's probably no need to check out the latest source from mercurial and install it yourself using setup.py.  Also, if you successfully run `python setup.py install`, it may not be easy to uninstall, whereas that should always be possible with the official debian packages that Ubuntu provides.